# read numbers from a text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a column of numbers from a text file that looks like this:

some text and numbers..., then:

```
 q-pt=    1    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0000000000
   1      -0.066408              0.0000000                      
   2      -0.053094              0.0000000                      
   3      -0.037643              0.0000000 
   ...
   156    3107.735577            6.8945617
...more text file
```

I am interested on reading the secound column the one that contain -0.066408, -0.053094 and so on.
The code I have try to write is somehow not doing the job without giving any error.I have tried this:

```
import re                                                                            
import sys                                                                           
from string import atof                                                              
from math import exp                                                                 
from numpy import *                                                                  

file1 = open('castepfreq.dat', 'w')                                                  
with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as file:                                           
    File = file.readlines()                                                          
    p1 = re.compile("q-pt=    1    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0000000000")  
    for i in range(len(File)):                                                       
        m1 = p1.search(File[i])                                                      
          if  m1:                                                                       
            read = int(float(File[i+1][10:23]))      
            freq = (read)                                                            
    print >> file1, freq    
file1.close()
```

If anyone can help me with this, it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can split on whitespace and then extract the second elements:

```
with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
    col = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
    print(col)
```

If your input is:

```
q-pt=    1    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0000000000
1      -0.066408              0.0000000
2      -0.053094              0.0000000
3      -0.037643              0.0000000
```

Output will be:

```
[('1', '-0.066408', '-0.053094', '-0.037643')]
```

Or using itertools and transposing:

```
from itertools import izip, islice, imap
with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
    col = islice(izip(*imap(str.split,f)), 1,2)
    print(list(col))
```

If you want to cast, cast the value to float:

```
 [float(line.split()[1]) for line in f]
```

Also if you want to skip the header and ignore `1` call `next(f)` on the file object before you use the rest of the code i.e:

```
with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
      next(f)
      col = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in f]
      print(list(col))
```

Which would output:

```
 [-0.066408, -0.053094, -0.037643]
```

If you have data you want to ignore and only start at the line `q-pt=..`, you can use itertools.dropwhile to ignore the lines at the start:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
    col = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in dropwhile(
           lambda x: not x.startswith("q-pt="), f)]
    print(list(col))
```

If you want to also ignore that line, you can call next again but this time on the dropwhile object:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
    dp = dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("q-pt="), f)
    next(dp)
    col = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in dp]
    print(list(col))
```

So for the input:

```
some 1 1 1 1 1
meta 2 2 2 2 2
data 3 3 3 3 3
and 4 4 4 4 4
numbers 5 5 5 5 5
q-pt=    1    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0000000000
1      -0.066408              0.0000000
2      -0.053094              0.0000000
3      -0.037643              0.0000000
3      -0.037643              0.0000000
```

The output will be:

```
[-0.066408, -0.053094, -0.037643, -0.037643]
```

For leading spaces,`lstrip` it off:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, imap, takewhile

with open('xd_geo_Efield.phonon') as f:
    # for python3 just use map
    dp = dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("q-pt="), imap(str.lstrip,f))
    next(dp)
    col = [float(line.split(None,2)[1]) for line in takewhile(lambda x: x.strip() != "", dp)]
    print(list(col))
```

`takewhile` will keep taking lines until we hit the first empty lines at the end of the file.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, the problem is that I have some text and other numbers above q-p= ...

Comment: So you just want to start at `q-p= ..`?

Comment: I want to read the lines after q-p=... so the last part is the one useful. Is there a way to spot the reading? I have text and numbers also after the last line in the input. Also there is a space in front of q-pt in my input. So the cod only works if i delete the space and the text underneath.Sorry, I am new in this.

Comment: I added how to remove the leading spaces, what do you mean by a way to spot the reading? What is considered the last good line?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to stop the reading. After the last line I have

q-pt=    1    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0000000000
1      -0.066408              0.0000000
2      -0.053094              0.0000000
3      -0.037643              0.0000000
3      -0.037643              0.0000000
                        Phonon Eigenvectors   
Mode Ion                X                                   Y                                   Z      
....

Comment: so `Phonon` is always there?

Comment: yes in the next line after the input listed above, with some spaces in the line in front of Phonon

Comment: Then we just need to go until we hit a blank line